# React-native-popup-menu on react-navigation header

Tags: react-native

I'm using redux with react-navigation and would like to show the popup when the user clicks on the button on the react-navigation header-right button.

I wrapped the context menu at the root of my apps, as below

```
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <MenuContext style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <AppWithNavigationState />
          </MenuContext>
      </Provider>
    )
```

in one of my screen, I have

```
static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'News',
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ paddingLeft:15, paddingRight:15 }}>
              <Icon name="more-vert" size={30} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    }
```

[image]

When the user clicks on the right button, it should be like this[image]

The menu items are dynamic, I will have to pull the data from one of my API and start rendering the menu data.

I've read through online it can be achieved using the context method, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my structure.

Could anyone advise me on this? 
And is it possible to render it with my local variable?

Answer (score 1):

The most custom way is to use [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal), when click the right button, called `this.refs.modalRef.showModal()`, which in your current page:

```
<View>
    <PopupModal ref="modalRef" />
</View>
```

The `PopupModal` like this:

```
export default class PopupModal extends Component {
    state = {
      show: false,
    }
    showModal() {
      this.setState({show: true});
    }
    closeModal = () => {
      this.setState({show: false});
    }
    return (
        <Modal
          transparent
          visible={this.state.show}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
        >
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.closeModal}>
                <View style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    backgroundColor: 'gray',
                }} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View></View> // your designed view, mostly position: 'absolute'
        </Modal>
    );    
}
```

You can also pass some data to PopupModal by `this.refs.modalRef.showModal(data)`, and in PopupModal:

```
showModal = (data) => {
  this.setState({ data, show: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu 
It works to me

```
 headerRight:<View  style={{marginRight:10}}>
        <Menu
            ref={this.setMenuRef}
            button={<Text onPress={this.showMenu}><Icon style={{color:screenProps.headerTitleStyle.color,fontSize:25,marginRight:5}} name="md-more"/></Text>}
        >
            <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Rate Us</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Share App</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Settings</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </View>,
```

Comment: I have used same npm. [issue](https://github.com/mxck/react-native-material-menu/issues/59) facing on Android real device:(